# What is the general name (e.g. facility location problem) for this problem (if any)?

Tags: modeling, reference-request, facility-location, terminology

I would like to know if there is a general name for the following problem:

1. We will open several facilities. Each facility has an associated facility type. There exists a given number of facility types. More than one facilities of same type can be open.
2. We want to decide

   - locations of facilities to open (e.g. boolean $x_{ki}$ which is true iff facility of type $k$ is open at location $i$)
     and
   - one-way supplier-relationships between pairs of facilities (e.g. boolean $y_{ij}$ which is true iff a facility at location $i$ is a supplier for the facility at location $j$)

   subject to some constraints (e.g. every open facility has to be supplied), and minimize some cost function which depends on distance between facilities as is often the case.
3. The number and allowed facility types of suppliers for each facility type are given as a parameter, for example, as a list of relationships of the form:

   $$m + n \to k$$

   indicating that facility of type $k$ must be supplied by a type $m$ facility and a type $n$ facility.

I think this problem somewhat resembles the [Multi-product capacitated facility location problem](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs11066-016-9102-6)<sup>1</sup>, but not quite. In the problem described above each facility is also a customer, and there is no clear distinction between customer and facility.

I also came across "Hierarchical facility location problem", and in particular [Multi-Level Facility Location Problems](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-32177-2_13)<sup>2</sup> (MLFLP). This also seems related, but the relationships given in (3) can be arbitrarily complex; whereas, the MLFLP seems to deal with few pre-defined levels.

I would like to know if there is something that is more similar.

Note: I believe that the problem described above must be well-studied and there should be a better match, because it basically captures the essence of economy in general, with complex products (and associated facilities) requiring other less-complex products (and associated facilities) as defined in (3). I am trying to find existing work which studied this problem.

---

<sub>References</sub>

<sub>[1] Montoya, A., Vélez–Gallego, M. C., Villegas, J. G. (2016). Multi-product capacitated facility location problem with general production and building costs. *NETNOMICS: Economic Research and Electronic Networking.* 17(1):47-70.</sub>

<sub>[2] Contreras, I., Ortiz-Astorquiza, C. (2019). Hierarchical Facility Location Problems. In *Location Science* (pp. 365-389). Springer, Cham.</sub>

Comment: What you are looking for is something like the multi-echelon/multi-stage supply chain models or special case of hub location-allocation problem. have you searched that?

Comment: @Omidi These things are all new to me. They do seem related but in the hierarchy they describe "plants" seem to be single layer with non-interacting elements; on the other hand, at this stage my focus is on the arbitrary hierarchy between plants defined by (3), not on HUBs and warehouses.

Comment: @ Omidi I guess the relations in (3) could be converted into a flow pattern, and facilities can be assigned to levels on the hierarchy depending on the complexity of the thing they produce. Then the models for multi-stage supply chain models and MLFPLs may be somewhat applicable, but still they don't seem to be addressing the same problem.

Comment: Please be aware that, there is not a reference that exactly being what you want and you would need to modify/combine some of them to turn out the desired results.